# Analysis differentiability proof involving sequences

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

So I was able to show part (a) using the limit definition of the derivative, but I don't know how to approach part (b). I thought maybe assuming that there did exist such a sequence (yn) but couldn't find a way to produce a contradiction. Help!

Comment: Do you know Taylor's theorem?

Comment: yeah the one that gives a statement about the remainder term?

Comment: Yes. Try to apply that to $f$, developing the power series at $0$. If there does not exist a sequence as in the claim, this would show that $f$ is represented by this power series. Why is this not true?